# how to calling python in codeigniter?

Tags: python, codeigniter

what's the solution?
I have entered the correct ip python but can't call the python
when running directly to else

```py
if($result = $this->curl($this->config->item('http://127.0.0.1:9999/app.py').'/'.$algorithm.'/'.json_encode($param)))
            {
                $json = json_decode($result);

                if(!empty($json->day1->index))
                {
                    $error = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    $error = true;
                    $etext .= 'Tidak dapat ditemukan hasil rekomendasi yang optimum, silahkan cek kembali preferensi anda.<br>';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $error = true;
                $etext .= 'Tidak dapat terhubung dengan server algoritma, silahkan ulangi kembali.<br>';
            }
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: you have two `http://` in url `'http://http://127.0.0.1:9999/app.py`. If app.py is Flask application then you should first run it manually and later use url with correct port and without `app.py`. If `app.py` is normal script - not www application - then you can't run it using url - like you can't run Excel or Word using url.

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong
already only `code` http://127.0.0.1:9999/app.py `code` can't log in either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update $this->config->item('http://127.0.0.1:9999/app.py') to 'http://127.0.0.1:9999/app.py'